# How to check whether user has any ERC1155 of specific contract in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc721, erc1155

I'm writing a staking smart-contract for ERC1155 contract (https://etherscan.io/address/0x2013ff029f9d3d31169f4fdc673c8b9fa0ce1fbd#code). When user wants to claim his reward, I need to check whether he owns any token of another ERC721 contract (https://etherscan.io/address/0x50add0f8541df53765848f6c73fecdc794fff985#code) to reward him with extra 10% of earned tokens. I can easily do it, using `balanceOf` of ERC721. If it returns 0, then user doesn't have any NFTs, so he won't get any extra tokens.

What would I do if bonus contract wasn't ERC721, but ERC1155? `balanceOf` of ERC1155 works in other way, it shows how many tokens of given id user has, when ERC721 shows total amount of tokens user owns. How could I check whether user has any ERC1155 of given contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a loop with `balanceOf` and increment the `id` or use `balanceOfBatch`. But I see on the contract you only have one collection => `TOKEN_ID == 0`, so u can use `balanceOf`.

Comment: There were mintpasses which you could buy at pre-sale and exhacnge them for pictures starting from the public sale. Those mintpasses have id == 0. All other NFTs have unique ids.